# Cannot construct thread to call templated member function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to construct a thread to run a templated member function:

```
struct S
{
    S()
    {
        std::thread t(&S::x<int>, this, p);       // The compiler error is passing p
        t.detach();
    }

    template<class T>
    void x(T& t)           
    {

    }

    int p;
};
```

The compiler error is not great but from trial & error I believe it refers to `p` being passed as argument in the thread constructor.

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:156:17: error: static assertion failed due to requirement '__is_invocable<void (S::*)(int &), S *, int>::value': std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  156 |         static_assert( __is_invocable<typename decay<_Callable>::type,
```

What's the way to do this?

Comment: Try `std::ref(p)`.

Comment: @Evg thank so so much. Please do put as an answer.

Comment: Please consider upvoting answers in the dupe question.

Comment: Or use lambda expressions : `std::thread t{ [&]{ p = 42; } };`